# Artificial Gravity - How much is needed per day?

Tags: health, artificial-gravity

Has any research been conducted or is anything known about how much time must be spent in 1G per 24 hours in order to preserve good health?

Assume that this refers to an extended space-journey. The artificial gravity could be provided by a module that is entered and used for exercise.

Comment: Relevant perhaps: https://medium.com/@chrisbbehrens/how-spacex-will-create-artificial-gravity-on-the-journey-to-mars-5da33e86aa9c

Comment: How should such a research possible if there is no centrifuge for 1 G at the ISS? This research could not be done on the surface of Earth.

Comment: I don't think you can answer it as specifically as this question asks. It is notable that much of the problem for recovery seems to be more related to vestibular stuff than to muscle loss...this argues for something less than a full g, all the time: https://www.telegraph.co.uk/science/2016/06/11/tim-peake-facing-months-of-recovery-following-six-month-space-mi/

Comment: Just spending time in 1 G would not do it anyway. Exercise in 1 G is necessary to preserve good health, on Earth as well as in orbit. Just resting in 1G would not work.

Comment: Nobody knows. There are studies simulating weightlessness by having people lie in bed.

Comment: Probably none, since astronauts have spent over a year in space in free fall.

Comment: Astronauts that have spent over a year in space in free fall may have lost muscles and bone density. More loss than while staying on Earth doing normal work plus exercise.

Comment: related but different [How would travel to Mars without artificial gravity affect a crew's initial experience in Mars gravity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16586/12102) and also [Least artificial gravity needed to maintain health on a one year space trip?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16571/12102)

Comment: Might be worthwhile to define "good health."  There are multiple aspects to be addressed, such as muscle atrophy, balance (inner ear stuff), changes in the ocular lens, etc...

Comment: I don't think it's currently possible to answer this question, humans in artificial gravity for long periods of time is an area of research that is almost completely unexplored